# Create a new record that has a belongs_to relationship, passing the ID of the model it belongs to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller

I'm trying to create a new contact object from an account object's "show" page. I know the below codes isn't correct. If I'm on the "show" page of the account how do I pass that accounts ID to the New contact form so I can create a new contact that belongs to that account?

Contact **belongs_to** Account

Account **has_many** Contacts

**Account "Show" view where I have a link to a new contact**

```
<%= link_to "Add Contact", new_account_contact_path(@account), class: 'btn' %>
```

**Contact Controller with Suggested Edits "New, Create" Actions**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :load_account
  respond_to :html, :json

...

  def create
    @contact = @account.contacts.new(params[:contact])
     if @contact.save
       redirect_to account_path(params[:account]), notice: "Successfully created Contact."
     else
       render :new
     end

  end

  def new
    @contact = @account.contacts.new
  end
...

end
```

**New Contact Form**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :firstname %>
    <%= f.input :lastname %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :phone %>
    <%= f.input :note %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**ERROR**

```
undefined method `contacts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f86c0c408d0>:0x007f86c0be7488>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= simple_form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
2:   <%= f.error_notification %>
3: 
4:   <div class="form-inputs">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the existence of `new_account_contact_path(@account)`, I will assume you have something like this in your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :contacts
end
```

If that is the case, your `contacts#create` route (and every `contact` route) will include an `:account_id` param. You can add a `before_filter` to automatically load the account in every action in the `ContactsController`, so you always have the relevant account object:

```
before_filter :load_account

def load_account
  @account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
end
```

Then in your new and create actions, it's a simple matter of building the object on the relation:

```
def new
  @contact = @account.contacts.new
end 

def create
  @contact = @account.contacts.new(params[:contact])
  ....
end
```

Also, I've never used `simple_form_for`, but it strikes me you might also need to pass in `@account` as a parameter so the form knows what url to post to.

Comment: This makes sense. After making your suggested changes I'm getting the following error: undefined method `contacts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f86c0b1bbd0>:0x007f86c0c24540>

Comment: Dave, the `contacts_path` using the POST method refers to the `contacts#create` action, but if you are using nested resources, the path will be `account_contacts_path`. Again, I've never used SimpleForm, but try this in your view: `simple_form_for [@account, @contact] do |f|`. If it works anything like the built-in form helpers, this will provide enough information to determine the correct path.

Comment: Thanks Zach. This worked <%= simple_form_for([@account, @contact])  do |f| %>

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your routes look something like

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :contacts
end
```

This way, `new_account_contact_path(@account)` would produce an URL like `/accounts/SOME_ID/contact/new`.

In `ContactsController`, then, you will have access to account id via `params[:account_id]`, so the proper way to create a contact for already know account would be

```
def new
  @account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
  @contact = @account.contacts.build(params[:contact])
end

def create
  @account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
  @contact = @account.contacts.build(params[:contact])
  # some stuff
end
```

Comment: As Zach Kemp proposed, you could actually set the account in a before filter.

Answer (score -1):

You should change in your `new` action:

```
def new
  @account = Account.find(params[:account])
  @contact = Contact.new
end
```

and in your `new` form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :firstname %>
    <%= f.input :lastname %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :phone %>
    <%= f.input :note %>
    <%= f.input :account_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => @account.id } %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Oh lol. You shouldn't be trusting the user THAT much to actually allow them to change `:account_id` in the form.

Comment: I agree, just want to answer your question in case you want to do that approach. The secure way to do that is change on create `@contact = current_user.contacts.build(params[:contact])`. It is hard to say sometimes what kind of answer you expect ;)